# Is this the right approach to count the number of base class objects created when there is a partial virtual inheritance involved?

Tags: c++, inheritance

From what I have learnt about virtual inheritance, whenever we have a **class A** (the base class), **classes B, C, D** (all these three virtually inherit **class A**) then if there is a **class derived** which inherits from **B**, **C** and **D** classes is instantiated then only a single object of **class A** would be created.

I tried to reason about the virtual inheritance by taking different cases:

**Case 1:**

Assume the **derived** class inherits only from **class B** and **C**. Even then only a single object of **class A** gets instantiated, right?

I tried to verify this using this code and it certainly seems to be the case:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    public:
    int a;
};
class B: virtual public A
{
  public:
  int b;
};
class C: virtual public A
{
    public:
    int c;
};
class D: virtual public A
{
    public:
    int d;
};
class derived: public B, public C
{
    public:
    int y;
};
int main() 
{
    derived dObj;
    cout<<&(dObj.B::a)<<'\n';
    cout<<&(dObj.C::a)<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
0x7ffc8adac1c0
0x7ffc8adac1c0
```

**Case 2:**

Assume the **derived** class inherits from **class B**, **C** and **D**, but **class D** doesn't inherit **class A** virtually. In this case, 2 objects of class A get instantiated, right? - One for **B**, **C** and one for **D**.

I tried to verify this using this code and it certainly seems to be the case:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    public:
    int a;
};
class B: virtual public A
{
  public:
  int b;
};
class C: virtual public A
{
    public:
    int c;
};
class D: public A
{
    public:
    int d;
};
class derived: public B, public C, public D
{
    public:
    int y;
};
int main() 
{
    derived dObj;
    cout<<&(dObj.B::a)<<'\n';
    cout<<&(dObj.C::a)<<'\n';
    cout<<&(dObj.D::a)<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
0x7ffd512429c8
0x7ffd512429c8
0x7ffd512429bc
```

Now here is my question:

Are my observations correct? That is, instead of just 3 classes - **B**, **C**, **D**, let's assume we have **n** classes that inherit **class A**, if out of them, **m** (1<=m<=n) classes are inherited by another class named **derived**, and if out of those **m** classes only **k** (0<=k<=m) classes inherit class **A** virtually then the number of objects of class **A** that get instantiated when instantiating the **derived** class would be = **1+m-k** (if k!=0) and **m** (when k=0), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the content written in the **cppreference** website it is indeed the case:

[See the first example under the virtual base classes section.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class#Virtual_base_classes)